# Floating multiple divs in one row

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, footer

I'm trying to show 4 widgets next to each other in a WordPress footer. I added into `functions.php` and `footer.php` files, so that the widget-content gets loaded.

But I'm unsure on how to display the widgets next to each other and starting at the same position as the header content, like in regular 4-column footer WordPress themes.

After a lot of tries, I managed to show them all in one row. `left-` & `right-margins` dont work anymore.

[image]

The css part looks like this:

```
.widgetfooter {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            display: flex;
            float: left;
            width: 15%;
            max-width: 1200px;
}
```

I includes the widget into the `footer.php` file like this:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'footer-sidebar1' ) ) : ?>
    <div class="footer-widget-area" >
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-sidebar1' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In the `functions.php`:

```
register_sidebar( array(   
    'name' => __( 'Footer Widget Area1', 'scentchild' ),
    'id' => 'footer-sidebar1',
    'description' => __( 'Appears on the footer, which has its own widgets', 'footer-sidebar1' ),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widgetfooter">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
```

Can somebody help me out with the css, please?

Comment: Have you tried `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:top`.

Comment: i tried using inline-block. when i am combining it with vertical align. but both doesnt seem to cause any effect :/

Comment: I meant without the `float:left`.

Comment: i removed all tags from the css class besides display:inline-block and vertical-align:top now. the position of the widgets doesnt move at all. but they all get squeezed together..

Comment: @blaner0, the information you provided is not enough for anyone to provide you with a definitive answer. We'd need to know what styles currently apply to your widgets and what is their specificity to tell you what to override them with. Besides, it also matters how you want them to be displayed at smaller widths. Without a [mcve] and more details it's hard to provide help. Considering it's a WP, I know most people find it difficult to provide **mcve**. So please provide a link where your issue can be inspected and i'll tell you how to do it

Comment: I don't mind browsing it, but it's not a publicly available IP (or at least it doesn't load for me). I've laid out the basics. Again, without a working example, it's hard to provide help. If I could inspect the thing, I'd know the exact specificity you need in order to apply CSS without breaking theme responsiveness.

Comment: unfortunately, i dont have it uploaded to a public server yet. but i am able to access the link from my phone by 3g. anyways - thanks to ur general layout explanation i believe i made it. THANK YOU so much.

Comment: You're correct, it works, but it's so slow it times out for me.

Comment: a further question.. if my css looks like this `.widget-child {
  margin: 0; 
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 25%; float: left;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}` how could i define it for mobile devices to be responsive? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure:

```
grandparent
  parent 
    child
    child
    child
    child
```

**Float** (in the middle):

```
grandparent { 
  text-align:center;
}
parent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: /* desired content width, in px, according to theme
              * mind responsiveness here...
              */
}
child {
  margin: 0; 
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 25%; 
  float: left;
}
```

---

**Flex**

(preferred, as you have more alignment options, especially if your children are smaller than parent available space and you want them to evenly distribute. It also allows vertical alignment - read more on flex if interested):

```
grandparent, parent { 
  display:flex; 
  justify-content: center; /* horizontal alignment, 
                            * if flex-direction is row (default) 
                            */
}
child {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
/* optional: */
parent {
  max-width: ... /* desired max-width here */ 
  align-items: center; /* vertical alignment */
}
```

Both of the above work if none of the rules are overridden by other rules. So you'd need to replace `grandparent`, `parent` and `child` with appropriate selectors.

You'll also need to specify rules for how to display the widgets at lower screen widths, inside `@media` queries, tuned in with your theme's responsiveness breakpoints.